# Call function from executable

Tags: c++, assembly, code-injection

I want to call a function from an executable. The only way to reach that process is to inject a dll in the parent process. I can inject a dll in the parent process but how do I call a function from the child process?
Something like

```
_asm
{ 
call/jmp address
}
```

doesnt work. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running inside the process, you need to know the offset of the function you want to call from the base of the module (the exe) which contains the function.  Then, you just need to make a function pointer and call it.

```
// assuming the function you're calling returns void and takes 0 params
typedef void(__stdcall * voidf_t)();

// make sure func_offset is the offset of the function when the module is loaded
voidf_t func = (voidf_t) (((uint8_t *)GetModuleHandle('module_name')) + func_offset);
func(); // the function you located is called here
```

The solution you have will work on 32bit systems (inline assembly is not permitted in 64 bit) if you know the address of the function, but you'll need to make sure you implement the calling convention properly.  The code above uses GetModuleHandle to resolve the currently loaded base of the module whose function you want to call.

Once you've injected your module into the running process ASLR isn't really an issue, since you can just ask windows for the base of the module containing the code you wish to call.  If you want to find the base of the exe running the current process, you can call GetModuleHandle with a parameter of NULL.  If you are confident that the function offset is not going to change, you can hard code the offset of the function you wish to call, after you've found the offset in a disassembler or other tool.  Assuming the exe containing the function isn't altered, that offset will be constant.

As mentioned in the comments, the calling convention is important in the function typedef, make sure it matches the calling convention of the function you're calling.

Comment: You should specify function calling convention in your pointer definition. Otherwise function call with incorrect convention will corrupt stack and lead to the program termination.

Answer (score 2):

### Execution Fundamentals

To call a function you need an address or a interrupt number.  The address is loaded into the Program Counter register and execution is transferred.  Some processors allow for "Software Interrupts", in which the program executes a special instruction that invokes the software interrupt.  This is the foundation for executing functions.

### More Background -- Relative Addresses

There are two common forms of executables:  Absolute Addressing and Relative (or Position Independ Code,PIC).  In absolute addressing, the functions are at hard-coded addresses.  The functions won't move.  Usually used in embedded systems.

In the relative addressing model, the addresses are relative to the value in the Program Counter register.  For example, your function may be 1024 bytes away, so the compiler would emit a relative branch instruction for 1024 bytes (away).

### Operating Systems and Moving Targets

Many operating systems load programs in different places for each invocation.   This means your executable may start at address 1000, and the next time at address 127654.  In these operating systems, *there is no guarantee that an executable will be launched at the same location each time*.

### Executing within your program

Executing functions within your program is easy.  The linker decides where all the functions will be located and determines how to execute them; whether to use absolute addressing, PIC or a mixture.

### Executing Functions in another Executable

With the above knowledge, there are issues with executing functions in another program:

- Location of the Function in the external executable
- Determining if the executable is active
- Calling protocol for the executable

Most executables do not contain any information about where their functions are, so you will need to know where it is.  You will also need to know if the function is absolute addressing or PIC.  You will also need to know if the function is in memory when you need it or if the OS has *paged* the function to the hard drive.

Knowing the function location is necessary.  However, the location is of no use if the OS has not loaded the executable.  Before you call a function in another executable, you will need to know if it is present in memory when the call is executed.

Lastly, you will need to know the protocol used for the external function.  For example, are the values passed by register?  Are they on the stack?  Are they passed by pointer (address)?

### A Solution: Shared Libraries

Operating systems (OS) have evolved to allow for dynamically sharing of functions.  These functions exist in Dynamically Linked Libraries (DLL) or Shared Library(.SO).  Your program tells the OS to load the library into memory, then you tell the OS to execute the function by giving it the name of the function.

The caveat is that the function you desire must be in a library.  If the executable doesn't use a shared library or the function you need is not in a library, then your mission is more difficult.